# jQuery Fade In Fade Out On MouseOver Via Multiple Images In A Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml, fade

So I am designing a website, and I want to be able to have each companies logo via an Image called via XHTML 1.0 Transitional fade in upon mouseover and fade out when no longer mousing over. I have jQuery installed and what not, I just don't know the code to this for each image or one image alone. I don't know JavaScript and or jQuery.

Thank you very much for future answers (and possible explanations),
Aaron Brewer

Comment: "I want to be able to have each companies logo via an Image called via XHTML 1.0 Transitional fade in"?

Comment: I want to be able to have each company's logo (Via An Image), in which that is called into the document via HTML (XHTML 1.0 Transitional To Be Exact), to fade in/fade out (Via jQuery, Via JavaScript) on MouseOver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a container for each image, otherwise there will be no element to trigger the mouse over when the image has faded out.

#### HTML

```
<div class="img-container">
   <img src="a.jpg" alt="a" />
</div>

<div class="img-container">
   <img src="b.jpg" alt="b" />
</div>

<div class="img-container">
   <img src="c.jpg" alt="c" />
</div>
```

#### jQuery

```
$('.img-container').each(function() {

   // Get a reference to the image.    
   var img = $(this).find('img');

   // Hide by default.
   img.hide();

   $(this).hover(function() {
       img.stop().fadeIn(500);
   }, function() {
       img.stop().fadeOut(500);
   });

});
```

Comment: @alex So, what does the .img-container stand for? I place this into the HTML Document's <head></head> tags right? How does it call a CSS Div if it's not part of the CSS document? I think I am starting to get what's going on here. A little explanation please? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Aaron Nope, this code will handle as many images as you like. I'll include some sample HTML.

Comment: @alex I put this coding into the HTML Document in between the header tags, and called out the CSS required and what not, but am getting nothing still.

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.logos-bottom').each(function() {

   // Get a reference to the image.    
   var img = $(this).find('img');

   // Hide by default.
   img.hide();

   $(this).hover(function() {
       img.stop.fadeIn(500);
   }, function() {
       img.stop.fadeOut(500);
   });

});
</script>

Comment: @alex Ahh, I see, thank you very much, but how would I come accross having it visible, but not just as visible until mouse over? Also, is it supposed to stop working after a few times?

Comment: @Aaron Use `opacity` property in CSS and `fadeTo()` in jQuery.

Comment: @alex Thank you so much Alex! I appreciate it! :-D

Answer (score 1):

perhaps this little live demo will get you in the right direction as it uses both CSS3 and jquery to do the fading, so if one fails, the other can take over. http://jsfiddle.net/robx/jrnFj/2/